# how to call the base function inside metaclass?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, metaclass

I want to have a similar customized function on many QGraphicsItem inherited class.

In practice like this:

```py
class QGraphicsRectItem(QGraphicsRectItem):
   def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
       print( "mouseMoveEvent :: event pos  =(%.1f, %.1f) " %( event.pos().x(), event.pos().y() )   )
       super().mouseMoveEvent( event )
class QGraphicsEllipseItem(QGraphicsEllipseItem):
   def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
       print( "mouseMoveEvent :: event pos  =(%.1f, %.1f) " %( event.pos().x(), event.pos().y() )   )
       super().mouseMoveEvent( event )
class QGraphicsPixmapItem(QGraphicsPixmapItem):
   def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
       print( "mouseMoveEvent :: event pos  =(%.1f, %.1f) " %( event.pos().x(), event.pos().y() )   )
       super().mouseMoveEvent( event )
class QGraphicsSimpleTextItem(QGraphicsSimpleTextItem):
   def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
       print( "mouseMoveEvent :: event pos  =(%.1f, %.1f) " %( event.pos().x(), event.pos().y() )   )
       super().mouseMoveEvent( event )
```

my idea is to use a metaclass of type(QGraphicsItem) but I have a problem to code this line:

```py
       super().mouseMoveEvent( event )
```

inside the metaclass

So, this code is not working:

```py
class QGraphicsItemMeta(type(QGraphicsItem)):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        print("name= %s" %(name))
        print("bases= %s" %(bases))
        print("dct=" %(dct) )

        newDct = {}
        for name, method in dct.items():
            if type(method) is FunctionType:
                print("method name= %s" % (name))
                newDct[name] = method
            else:
                print("attribut name= %s" % (name))
                newDct[name] = method

        def mouseMoveEventMyCustomize(self, event):
            print( "mouseMoveEventNew :: event pos  =(%.1f, %.1f) " %( event.pos().x(), event.pos().y() )   )
            super().mouseMoveEvent( event )

        newDct['mouseMoveEvent'] = mouseMoveEventMyCustomize

        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, newDct)

class QGraphicsRectItem(QGraphicsRectItem, metaclass = QGraphicsItemMeta):
    pass
class QGraphicsEllipseItem(sEllipseItem, metaclass = QGraphicsItemMeta):
    pass
class QGraphicsPixmapItem(QGraphicsPixmapItem, metaclass = QGraphicsItemMeta):
    pass
class QGraphicsSimpleTextItem(QGraphicsSimpleTextItem, metaclass = QGraphicsItemMeta):
    pass
```

inside the metaclass, instead of this:

```py
       super().mouseMoveEvent( event )
```

I have tried this:

```py
       bases().mouseMoveEvent( event )
```

but no success.

How can I fix it ?

Comment: But it really makes no sense to use a metaclass here... just use inheritance, the mixin pattern.

Comment: but I think you'd need something like `klass = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, newDct)`, **before** `def mouseMoveEventMyCustomize(...)`, then after, when defining, use `super(klass, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)`, then `klass.mouseMoveEven = mouseMoveEventMyCustomize` and finally, `return klass`, but again, just use a mixin here

Comment: I agree, I don't see any benefit in using metaclasses, just use mixins. It also is a ***terrible*** idea to name derived classes *exactly* like those from which they inherit.

Comment: Thanks all for the mixin. I didn't know it. I will post an update feedback in the question of the top.

Comment: @Musicamate: I define the mixin class in a separate file, and import it in the main.
When things go wrong/crazy in the main, I remove the import, and use the old
default one to debug easier. So, no code refactoring is need when same name.

Comment: Don't update the question with the solutions. You can post an answer for your own question.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga : yes, your solution works. I applied your solution in an update of initial question.

Comment: @chepner : sorry, Musicamante told me to **not** do this !  a proper feedback feature is really missing on this site.

Comment: @jljPatch If the code you added solves your problem then post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**: feedback applying the ***metaclass solution*** given by [juanpa.arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga) in the context of the original question.

```py
import sys
from types import FunctionType
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class QGraphicsItemMeta(type(QGraphicsItem)):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        print("name= %s" %(name))
        print("bases= %s" %(bases))
        print("dct=" %(dct) )

        newDct = {}
        for name, method in dct.items():
            if type(method) is FunctionType:
                print("method name= %s" % (name))
                newDct[name] = method
            else:
                print("attribut name= %s" % (name))
                newDct[name] = method

        klass= super().__new__(cls, name, bases, newDct)

        def mouseMoveEventMyCustomize(self, event):
            print( "mouseMoveEventNew :: event pos  =(%.1f, %.1f) " %( event.pos().x(), event.pos().y() )   )
            super(klass, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

        klass.mouseMoveEvent = mouseMoveEventMyCustomize

        return klass

class QGraphicsRectItem(QGraphicsRectItem, metaclass = QGraphicsItemMeta):
    pass
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self ):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__()

        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.scene.setSceneRect( 0.0, 0.0, 640.0, 480.0 )

        view= QGraphicsView()
        view.setScene(self.scene)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget( view )
        self.setLayout( layout )

        self.myRect= QGraphicsRectItem( 0,  0, 100, 100)
        self.scene.addItem( self.myRect )

        self.myRect.setFlag( QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable,      True  )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: feedback applying the ***Mixin solution*** given by experts in the comments

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class QGraphicsItemMixin( QGraphicsItem ):
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        print( "QGraphicsItemMixin :: mouseMoveEvent :: event pos  =(%.1f, %.1f) " %( event.pos().x(), event.pos().y() )   )
        super().mouseMoveEvent( event )

class QGraphicsRectItem(QGraphicsRectItem, QGraphicsItemMixin):
    pass
class QGraphicsEllipseItem(QGraphicsEllipseItem, QGraphicsItemMixin):
    pass                  
                          
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self ):  
        super(QWidget, self).__init__()
                          
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.scene.setSceneRect( 0.0, 0.0, 640.0, 480.0 )
                          
        view= QGraphicsView()
        view.setScene(self.scene)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget( view )
        self.setLayout( layout )

        self.myRect= QGraphicsRectItem( 0,  0, 100, 100)
        self.scene.addItem( self.myRect )
        self.myEllipse= QGraphicsEllipseItem( 100, 200, 100, 100)
        self.scene.addItem( self.myEllipse )

        self.myRect.setFlag( QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable,   True  )  
        self.myEllipse.setFlag( QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable,True  )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

This case is overkill for metaclasses, although the approach might work.

Anyway, regarding `super()` that won't be a trivial thing exactly because the parameterless form of `super` will only work when the call is written inside a method hardcoded in the class body.

The easiest thing to do is to have a reference to the current class - the class you are patching, in a nonlocal variable in the `__new__` method itself - this variable will be the actuall class, which is the return value of `super()`, when called in the `metaclass.__new__` method.

So, your code, if you get no metaclass conflict with the classes in PyQt can work as this:

```
class QGraphicsItemMeta(type(QGraphicsItem)):
    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, dct):   # __new__ actually gets the metaclass itself, not "cls"
        ...
        cls = None  # just a placeholder - this is the variable that will be used inside the new method
        newDct = {}
        for name, method in dct.items():
            if type(method) is FunctionType:
                print("method name= %s" % (name))
            else:
                print("attribut name= %s" % (name))
            newDct[name] = method

        def mouseMoveEventMyCustomize(self, event):
            # nonlocal cls  # <- the statement is really not needed, as cls will be read only
                            # inside the method.
            print( "mouseMoveEventNew :: event pos  =(%.1f, %.1f) " %( event.pos().x(), event.pos().y() )   )
            # here we used the paramtrized version of `super` refering 
            # to "cls"
            super(cls, self).mouseMoveEvent( event )

        newDct['mouseMoveEvent'] = mouseMoveEventMyCustomize

        cls = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, newDct)
        # the nonlocal variable now contains a reference to the newly created class
        return cls
```

As I stated, however, you are better of without metaclasses at all in this situation - as any Qt also does use metaclasses, and you will be depending on it not conflicting with yours.

An approach using init_subclass is just:

```
    
from functools import wraps
def track_mouse(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self, event):
        pos = event.pos()
        print(f"mouseMoveEventNew :: event pos ={pos.x:.1f}, {pos.y():%.1f}")
        return func(self, event)
    wrapper._customized = True 
    return wrapper

class MouseMonitorMixin:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(*args, **kwargs)
        original = getattr(cls, "mouseMoveEvent", None)
        if not original or getattr(original, "_customized", False):
            return
        setattr(cls, "mouseMoveEvent", track_mouse(original))
```

And just inherit your classes from that, along with the original class they inherit from:

```
class QGraphicsRectItem(QGraphicsRectItem, MouseMonitorMixin):
    pass
...
```

Comment: jsbueno: thanks for your idea. One question: MouseMonitorMixin has no base class, then its base class is object, then how is working _super()_ in the line _super().__init_subclass__(*args, **kwargs)_ of the function \_\_init\_subclass\_\_ ? it looks like 'recurssif' to me, but, I guess that I miss the point.

Comment: Object does have a do-nothing `__init_subclass__` method, just for this. The reason one calls super when implementing it is so that that the mixin becomes composible with others, and one doesn't need to know about the any ones.